# Reversed reading of batch output to string

Tags: batch-file, traceroute

I've got the following output, from a tracert:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\test>tracert speedtest.danskkabeltv.dk

Tracing route to speedtest.danskkabeltv.dk [62.61.131.22]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.59.17.1
  3     4 ms     1 ms     2 ms  172.17.2.137
  4     *        1 ms     1 ms  172.17.4.51
  5     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  172.17.4.10
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     3 ms     2 ms     2 ms  0xc2ffb9c1.linknet.dk.telia.net [194.255.185.193]
  9     *        3 ms     2 ms  0xc2ff8561.linknet.dk.telia.net [194.255.133.97]
 10     5 ms     8 ms    12 ms  0xc2ff8562.linknet.dk.telia.net [194.255.133.98]
 11     4 ms     4 ms     3 ms  87.72.143.234
 12     4 ms     3 ms     3 ms  62.61.140.26.generic-hostname.arrownet.dk [62.61.140.26]
 13     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  62.61.140.42.generic-hostname.arrownet.dk [62.61.140.42]
 14     3 ms     2 ms     2 ms  speedtest01-hor.aplus.dk [62.61.131.22]

Trace complete.
```

What i need to do, is read the text from right side to left. So that if i perform a for /f, the the first one will be the furthest to the right, and so forth.

Can this be done?

Comment: If you were on a Unix or BSD it would be a one liner, but I dont know much about Windows. BTW if you were ever able to figure this out it would be good to add an answer of your own so that somebody can benefit in the future.